# MS ACESS Error when accessing

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I am developing an enrolment system. But i am receiving this error: `You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression..`

I am using the following code:

```
Private Function RefreshAdvisoryList()

    Dim vRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSQL As String

    'clear list
    txtsection.Clear

    'On Error GoTo ReleaseAndExit

        sSQL = "SELECT tblSection.SectionID, tblSection.SectionTitle, tblAdviser.SchoolYear, tblDepartment.DepartmentTitle, tblYearLevel.YearLevelTitle, tblAdviser.TeacherID" & _
                " FROM (tblDepartment INNER JOIN (tblYearLevel INNER JOIN tblSection ON tblYearLevel.YearLevelID = tblSection.YearLevelID) ON tblDepartment.DepartmentID = tblSection.DepartmentID) INNER JOIN tblAdviser ON (tblSection.SectionID = tblAdviser.SectionID) AND (tblDepartment.DepartmentID = tblAdviser.DepartmentID)" & _
                " GROUP BY tblSection.SectionID, tblSection.SectionTitle, tblAdviser.SchoolYear, tblDepartment.DepartmentTitle, tblYearLevel.YearLevelTitle, tblAdviser.TeacherID" & _
                " HAVING (((tblTeacher.TeacherID)='" & curTeacher.TeacherID & "') AND tblSection.SchoolYear='" & Me.txtSchoolYear.Text & "')" & _
                " ORDER BY tblAdviser.SchoolYear DESC;"


    If ConnectRS(con, vRS, sSQL) = False Then
        'fatal
        'temp
        MsgBox "Unable to connect Teacher's Advisory Recordset.", vbCritical
        'GoTo ReleaseAndExit
    End If

    If AnyRecordExisted(vRS) = True Then
        While vRS.EOF = False
        txtsection.AddItem vRS!SectionTitle
        vRS.MoveNext
   Wend
    End If

'Exit Function
'ReleaseAndExit:
'    Set vRS = Nothing
End Function
```

Take a look at this screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause references these 2 fields:

- `tblTeacher.TeacherID`
- `tblSection.SchoolYear`

The `SELECT` field list includes:

- `tblAdviser.TeacherID`
- `tblAdviser.SchoolYear`

Change the query so that all references to `TeacherID` come from the same table.  Do the same for `SchoolYear`.

BTW, `tblTeacher` is not even included among the query's data sources.

If possible, start an Access session and use the query designer to build this query.  It will help you avoid this type of error.  Once you have a query which works in Access, then adapt your code to produce the same working SQL statement.

Comment: can i just change the 2 fields in HAVING clause to match the SELECT fields?

Comment: That is the first thing I would try.  What happens when you try that as a new query in Access?

Answer (score 0):

Group by has to be used with a aggregate function so that combined result for a group can be retrieved, you have not used any aggregate function.

Refer - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Remove group by from your query and add the having clause in the where clause.

Explain what type of data you are expecting so that we can help you in the query.